# ColdFusion Loop Through TXT File

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have a text file in the format:

```
ABC | 123
DEF | 456
```

I've tried all sorts of things but can't get out what I need. What I need to be able to do is loop through each row and pick out (in the above example) `ABC` and `123` separately, as well as `DEF` and `456`

```
<cfloop file="#application.sLibPath#301.txt" index="FileLine">
    <cfoutput>#listgetat(FileLine,1)#, #listgetat(FileLine,2)#</cfoutput><br>
</cfloop>
```

I've tried that but it doesn't work, i.e., it breaks. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: fyi - there are also [listFirst](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListFirst) and [listLast](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListLast) functions that would work for you're doing. They allow you to pass in a delimiter just like listGetAt

Comment: Just a note (@Miguel-F has given you the correct answer), but when you're posting a question involving an error, don't just say "there's an error", post the actual error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the delimiter portion of the `ListGetAt` function. By default the delimiter is a `,` (comma) but in your case you want a `|` character.

Try this:

```
<cfoutput>#listgetat(FileLine,1,"|")#, #listgetat(FileLine,2,"|")#</cfoutput><br>
```

Note: looking at your example data this might include some white space as well. Something like "ABC " and " 123" (notice the spaces). You can use the `Trim()` function to remove those.

```
<cfoutput>#Trim(listgetat(FileLine,1,"|"))#, #Trim(listgetat(FileLine,2,"|"))#</cfoutput><br>
```

[Documentation for the ListGetAt function](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_12.html)

Comment: Excellent thanks - noticed the white space issue but thanks for the workaround

Comment: @JanuszJasinski - Small note. Most list functions ignore empty elements by default. If the lines can sometimes contain empty elements, you may want to use `listToArray(list, delimiter, includeEmptyFields)` instead.

Comment: Well.. you would if you were using CF9+ ;-) I forgot the includeEmptyFields parameter [was not added until CF9](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f0f.html).